# Android: Is possible to copy fingerprints from one device to other?

Tags: android, fingerprint

I would like to ask, that is possible o copy/transfer via some Android API fingerprints from one device to other? I'm trying to create user verification app which should be based on provided user fingerprint from other child devices.

Many thanks for any advice or tutorial.

Comment: No. Fingerprints are stored on the device and cannot be moved. No API exists as of right now to do that.

Comment: (almost) everything is possible with root access. Including copying fingerprint, as I think/

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko: _"everything is possible with root access. Including copying fingerprint"_. No, not unless the implementation is buggy. The fingerprint data is supposed to be kept in a separate area that cannot be accessed directly by the Android OS, even with root access.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not provide any resource regarding accessing finger print, You only validate using Android provide code.  but  you can not use it in android device. it is unique for every device.

you can refer [here](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-does-android-save-your-fingerprints)